# Extension method question

Tags: .net, wpf, oop, .net-4.0, extension-methods

Why the code bellow (.NET-4, Extension method) does not leave me using `Application.DoEvents();`?

```
/// <summary>
/// Invokes in the Dispatcher an empty action.
/// An thread safe equivalent of the ancient Application.DoEvents.
/// </summary>
public static void DoEvents(this Application a)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
        new Action(delegate { })); 
}
```

## EDIT

updated version after SLaks remark

```
    public static void DoEvents(this Application a)
    {
        if (a != null)
        {
            a.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
                new Action(delegate { }));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using your parameter?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @mcabral: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502037/where-is-the-application-doevents-in-wpf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only call extension methods an an instance.

Thus, you would be able to write `Application.Current.DoEvents()`, since that's an `Application` instance.
However, you cannot invoke it on the type itself.

Comment: just can't make answer yet :)

Comment: Only by creating your own class with a similar name and making a normal static method.  (eg, `MyAppliction.DoEvents()`)