# What is equivalent to Application.DoEvents() in WPF applications

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, doevents

From MSDN, it seems that Application.DoEvents() is available in Windows.Forms. What would be the equivalent thing in WPF.

Comment: Are you porting a legacy VB 6 application that uses `DoEvents`? Why do you think you need an equivalent to it?

Comment: There is no equivalent.  Stop doing that.  No.

Comment: @Cody: No, I am not actually porting anything. I just needed the feature as described.

Comment: FYI.  Calling System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents() works fine in WPF, and will run your dispatcher events, etc.  You just need to add a reference to it.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83, WinForms' `DoEvents` won't pump Dispatcher operations (queued with `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`). [More details](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21642381/1768303).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the Application.DoEvents() in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502037/where-is-the-application-doevents-in-wpf)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You shouldn't be using it even in Windows Forms. Don't perform long-running tasks on the UI thread - use a background thread and use the `Dispatcher` to update the UI as required. Any use of `Application.DoEvents` is basically a code smell. I don't know whether there *is* an equivalent in WPF, but you should try to avoid it even if there is.

Comment: I would not call it a code smell, because sometimes you need to manipulate UI objects in the computation (and dont do anything else than that) and in that case it is actually cleaner to call  an equivalent of DoEvents().

Comment: @TomasGrosup: I'd say there are *very rarely* cases where it makes sense to use `Application.DoEvents`. It's pretty unusual for long-running work to be *purely* UI creation... and it would generally be cleaner to perform all other computation first, then just marshal to the UI thread for the purely UI part later.

Comment: Okay so say you update objects that are data bound, and all your OnPropertyChanged have fired. you then want to print a visual, surely it is not a code smell to call DoEvents() before printing the WPF visual to ensure that all the visuals have updated before you print.

Comment: Well what's initiating the printing, and why would that be executing before all the changes have become visible? And why would printing not re-render anyway?

Comment: I do all my logic in a background worker thread -- still brings the UI thread to a halt -- if I call Application.DoEvents() in a Timer, etc. the application runs flawless... until it eventually freezes because WPF doesn't like it... -- so, clearly, "Don't perform long-running tasks on the UI thread" isn't enough -- what else do we have to do to make WPF get off it's arse and handle its events?

Comment: @BrainSlugs83: Doing all the work in a background worker thread *really* shouldn't bring the UI to a halt. It sounds like there are other issues, which should be asked about in a separate question. `Application.DoEvents` may address the immediate symptoms, but it *isn't* the right answer.

Comment: I agree it isn't the *right* answer -- but unless we're all making the same mistakes (as this problem seems to be very common), neither is doing all your work in a background worker thread. :-/ -- thanks @JonSkeet, I will consider opening a new question.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83: I don't think it *is* very common, in terms of the UI locking up when you don't have any long-running tasks in it. I think it's more likely that you either *do* have a long-running task in the UI thread without realizing it, or you're doing something is theoretically short-lived, but needs to acquire a lock which is actually held by a long-running task elsewhere, which is just as bad.

Comment: Well, it seems to be asked commonly enough.  Perhaps you're right.  But, I ended up figuring out my scenario -- *I* was definitely not running code on the UI thread; my project was an Office Add-in though -- and when I invoked callbacks against the VSTO object model from background threads (no Dispatcher.Invoke, etc. it was definitely code running on the background thread), it turned out Word was somehow doing work on the main thread.  I solved the issue by creating a separate thread to instantiate and show my dialog from, as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20534223/398630

Answer (score 23):

While i agree with the Skeet you can find a WPF method like that on the [documentation page of the `DispatcherFrame`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherframe.aspx)

Comment: Actually there are cases where is required, even if you are not performing a long running action on the UI thread. I have a user control where there is a long running action as a BackGroundWorker which also updates UI using dispatcher. However the control stops responding to Canvas.SetTop/Canvas.SetLeft while the backgroundworker is running, only using this code from MSDN can one get around it.

Comment: @MalcolmMcCaffery: That sounds weird, i have never encountered anything like that, after all the whole point of the `BackgroundWorker` is to keep the UI responsive. Maybe you are issuing too many updates in a small amount of time so it chokes...