# MessageBox.Show makes DirectShow go

Tags: c#, wpf

Does anyone have any insight as to what can cause a scenario where if you were to call

```
mediaControl.Run();
```

that it won't actually start rendering video until this is called

```
MessageBox.Show("");
```

I couldn't figure out why the media wasn't running even when getstate returned that it was running until i return the HRESULT which said sure its running... but only displays video on the window when a messagebox is shown.

The weird thing is that if you dismiss the messagebox, and rendering pauses... but if you called it again say 5 seconds after, it continue to works.

Furthermore... if you dismiss the messagebox and have a continous loop right after it that sleeps the thread indefinitely, it continues to render.

I have been banging my head all day with this trying to figure out why a messagebox is key... but ultimately, I can't have a messagebox display.

Any random ideas would be helpful too... thanks.

Cheers.

Comment: It would help to know the code you are using.  If its a short, post all of it or try to pick out the needed parts if the project is really big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing MessageBox.Show() does is to run the message loop. You may be able to replace it with simulated `DoEvents()` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4502200/60761))

But there probably is a serious problem in your code surrounding this.

Comment: Link wasn't helpful... but mentioning the message loop gave me the clue I needed. I am accessing User32.dll to do a PostThreadMessage and when stopping at that break point every so often the video renders... so now I should be on track... no need for a messagebox. Thank you. Not sure who voted me down, it was an honest question but oh well... you pointed me in the direction i need to go. Cheers.