# Alternative to Application.DoEvents() in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a following situation

```
kl.KeyDown += CheckPwd;
while(flag)
   System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();

//continue other code based on "Success"

//This will be called for every keydown
void CheckPwd(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   //some code here
   if(....)
   {
       flag = true;
       Success = true;   
       kl.KeyDown -= CheckPwd;   
   }
   else
   {
       flag = true;
       Success = false;
       kl.KeyDown -= CheckPwd;
   }
}
```

Here I want to avoid using `Application.DoEvents()`. I tried using `ManualResetEvent`, but when I call `WaitOne()` it is blocking current thread, and causing this, `CheckPwd` is not firing up. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Appears to be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: @SriramSakthivel here i want to avoid Application.DoEvents() but achive same result.

Comment: Your "success" code should simply be in the `CheckPwd` method, rather than in your earlier section of code, so that you don't *need* to "wait" for the event to be fired.

Comment: @Servy thanks, but i have to do different work(success code) from different places, actually i am using kl.KeyDown += CheckPwd; from different places

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the Application.DoEvents() in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502037/where-is-the-application-doevents-in-wpf)

Comment: @HenkHolterman He has said he is looking for a more appropriate approach, rather than using a direct equivalent of `DoEvents`...

Comment: @Servy - not totally clear but you're probably right.

Comment: @Rajeev - this would be much clearer in terms of what you want, now it is in pieces of a (broken) solution.

Comment: `async`/`await` removes the need for `DoEvents`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new `Success` event, fire it when you hit your success condition, and then put the code you need to execute on Success in an event handler for that event:

define the event:

```
public event Action Success;
```

Attach the handler:

```
kl.KeyDown += CheckPwd;
Success += DoSuccessStuff;
```

Fire the event:

```
void CheckPwd(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   //some code here
   if(...)
   {
       flag = true;
       Success = true;   
       kl.KeyDown -= CheckPwd;   
       if(Success != null) Success();
   }
   //...
```