# IInvokeProvider.Invoke in NUnit Test

Tags: c#, wpf, nunit, ui-automation

I have a WPF user control that I am writing some unit tests for using NUnit.  One of the tests displays the control on a window and clicks a button on the control.  After which it looks to confirm the correct result was received.

Using RaisedEvents it looks something like this and works correctly.

```
MyButton.RaiseEvent(buttonArgs);
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

I am trying to do the same thing using the automation framework.  Something like:

```
ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(MyButton);
IInvokeProvider invokeProv = (IInvokeProvider)(peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke));
invokeProv.Invoke();
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Now in this case the assert fails (as expected) because Invoke is called asynchronously and has not yet occurred at the time of the assertion.

I was hoping that I could resolve this by calling Invoke on a separate thread and waiting for it to complete.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(invokeProv.Invoke);
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```

However this still fails.  As does just sleeping:

```
invokeProv.Invoke();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Showing a dialog and forcing the user to continue, does however work.

```
invokeProv.Invoke();
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("");
```

So I think there is some sort of setup I need to do to get things to behave the way I like.  Perhaps setting up a separate thread for the dispatcher, or the Window.  I'm sure there are examples of this out there, but I seem to not be searching on the right key words.  Note that NUnit is requiring me to run my unit tests with the RequiresSTA attribute.

Comment: Ok I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your conclusion is correct. `IInvokeProvider.Invoke` is async the same way `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` is async. It just puts a message into the queue for the dispatcher to process. However you are not starting the thread's dispatcher until you show the message box. You probably want something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502037/where-is-the-application-doevents-in-wpf/11899439#11899439) to process the dispatcher operations in the test thread.

```
public static void DoEvents()
{
    DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrame), frame);
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
}

public static object ExitFrame(object f)
{
    ((DispatcherFrame)f).Continue = false;
    return null;
}
```

Which can be used like so:

```
ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(MyButton);
IInvokeProvider invokeProv = (IInvokeProvider)(peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke));
invokeProv.Invoke();
DoEvents();
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```