# WPF UI not refresh (Revit pluggin)

Tags: wpf, user-interface, resize, refresh, revit

I have developed a pluggin on Revit in WPF but I have a problem.

I load a family from a button in the user interface but the user interface does not update or refresh.

I force the refresh by resizing the window.

I did some research on the net but I did not find any information.

I post a youtube link to show you the manipulation.

Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gb_YZH6i9s&feature=youtu.be

Comment: The dialog with your WPF UI is shown modeless or modal?

Comment: I use modal dialog. I noticed that this does not happen every time (it's random sometimes the user interface updates, sometimes not)

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of similar issues in the past. In general I prefer using Windows Forms over WPF, since they seem to be easier to handle. Afaik, all WPF problems have been solved, though. Here is a whole list of related discussions on The Building Coder:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/wpf/

Answer (score 0):

You can try a "WPF DoEvents" after the loading of your family. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11899439/200443